# Realmで複数条件を指定する

Tags: swift, realm

`Realm`で複数条件を指定してデータを削除するにはどうすればよろしいでしょうか？
例えば「Aが1かつ'CCC'」のような条件の時などです。
また、自分も試しにデータを削除してみようとしたのですが、「`'RLMResults' is not convertible to 'RLMObject'`」というエラーが以下の`realm.deleteObject`の行で出てしまいます。
どうすれば複数条件を指定してデータを削除できるでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

```
        let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
        realm.transactionWithBlock( { () -> Void in
            realm.deleteObject(Word.objectsWhere(""))
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'RLMResults' is not convertible to 'RLMObject'

が出ている原因は

```
realm.deleteObject(Word.objectsWhere(""))
```

で`deleteObject`に`objectsWhere`の結果を渡しているからじゃないでしょうか。

```
- (RLMResults *)objectsWhere:(NSString *)predicateFormat, ...;

- (void)deleteObject:(RLMObject *)object;
```

質問のような書き方で処理したいのであれば`deleteObjects`を使う必要があると思います。

```
- (void)deleteObjects:(id)array;
```

----- 追記 -----
[公式](http://realm.io/jp/docs/cocoa/0.91.1/#section-12)を見た限りだと複数条件の指定はこんな感じでいけるみたいですね。

```
// Query using a predicate string
var tanDogs = Dog.objectsWhere("color = 'tan' AND name BEGINSWITH 'B'")

// Query using an NSPredicate object
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "color = %@ AND name BEGINSWITH %@", "tan", "B")
tanDogs = Dog.objectsWithPredicate(predicate)
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。一度deleteObjectsで試してみたいと思います。

Comment: @kojianu 回答少し追記しました。

Comment: deleteObjectsで削除することができました。
また、ご提示の方法で複数条件の指定ができました。大変ありがとうございました。